# Kubuntu 20.04 UEFI suddly not booting

Tags: kubuntu, uefi

My Kubuntu 20.04 UEFI install on a Dell Precison T5810 suddenly stopped booting. The system appears to be stuck at the Dell logo screen.

I've tried the `Boot-Repair-Disk`

```
boot-repair-4ppa130                                              [20211126_1244]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================



/usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd_terminal.sh: line 177: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sda2,
using the following options:        sda1/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in sda2/fstab
Mount sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/etc/default/grub

================= Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of sda2 ==================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.13

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,46dfc399-6a58-480f-beb5-ffda10122892,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,VerbatimSTORE N GO,0x0)..BO
Boot0002* P0: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L  BBS(HD,P0: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L,0x0)..BO
Boot0003* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,USB Storage Device,0x0)..BO
Boot0004* P0: PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8ABSH        BBS(CDROM,P0: PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8ABSH    ,0x0)..BO
Boot0005* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,Onboard NIC,0x0)..BO
Boot0006  UEFI: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L    HD(1,GPT,46dfc399-6a58-480f-beb5-ffda10122892,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIbootbootx64.efi)..BO
Boot0007* UEFI: VerbatimSTORE N GO  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(21,0)..BO

uname -r
5.3.0-28-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,46dfc399-6a58-480f-beb5-ffda10122892,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,VerbatimSTORE N GO,0x0)..BO
Boot0002* P0: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L  BBS(HD,P0: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L,0x0)..BO
Boot0003* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,USB Storage Device,0x0)..BO
Boot0004* P0: PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8ABSH        BBS(CDROM,P0: PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8ABSH    ,0x0)..BO
Boot0005* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,Onboard NIC,0x0)..BO
Boot0006  UEFI: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L    HD(1,GPT,46dfc399-6a58-480f-beb5-ffda10122892,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIbootbootx64.efi)..BO
Boot0007* UEFI: VerbatimSTORE N GO  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(21,0)..BO
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS entry (sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04 6.04-pre2-11-gbf6db5b4*..........................................G....2....0..........
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 2003800 of /dev/sdb for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on sda2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,46dfc399-6a58-480f-beb5-ffda10122892,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,VerbatimSTORE N GO,0x0)..BO
Boot0002* P0: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L  BBS(HD,P0: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L,0x0)..BO
Boot0003* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,USB Storage Device,0x0)..BO
Boot0004* P0: PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8ABSH        BBS(CDROM,P0: PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8ABSH    ,0x0)..BO
Boot0005* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,Onboard NIC,0x0)..BO
Boot0006  UEFI: INTEL SSDSC2BW240A3L    HD(1,GPT,46dfc399-6a58-480f-beb5-ffda10122892,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFI\boot\bootx64.efi)..BO
Boot0007* UEFI: VerbatimSTORE N GO  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(21,0)..BO
This session has been detected as 'live' because /proc/cmdline contains (boot=casper)
This session has been detected as 'live' because df -Th / contains overlay

85fa9d77b929ec4231aba29476574eb6   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk identifier: 2F28D532-79B2-44F0-9CB1-AA892EFB7353
        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
sda2  1050624 468860927 467810304 223.1G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 7.3 GiB, 7864320000 bytes, 15360000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x20ac7dda
      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1       3224498923 3657370039  432871117 206.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb2       3272020941 5225480974 1953460034 931.5G 16 Hidden FAT16
sdb3                0          0          0     0B 6f unknown
sdb4         50200576  974536369  924335794 440.8G  0 Empty
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk zram0: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors
Disk zram1: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors
Disk zram2: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors
Disk zram3: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors
Disk zram4: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors
Disk zram5: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors
Disk zram6: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors
Disk zram7: 2 GiB, 2099744768 bytes, 512633 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:240GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA INTEL SSDSC2BW24:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:240GB:240GB:ext4::;
sdb:7864MB:scsi:512:512:loop:Verbatim STORE N GO:;
1:0.00B:7864MB:7864MB:fat32::;
zram5:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram3:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram1:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram6:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram4:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram2:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram0:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram7:2100MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:2100MB:2100MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                             
├─sda1 vfat     04F4-4A6B                            46dfc399-6a58-480f-beb5-ffda10122892       EFI System Partition
└─sda2 ext4     2c95e78c-070a-4308-bc21-e56e68be8992 98efa4c2-1c8f-439a-b89d-0c29eecd1756       
sdb    vfat     5059-2494                                                                       
zram0                                                                                           
zram1                                                                                           
zram2                                                                                           
zram3                                                                                           
zram4                                                                                           
zram5                                                                                           
zram6                                                                                           
zram7                                                                                           

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

       Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1   503.2M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2   191.5G   7% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sdb      6.4G  13% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda2   rw,relatime
sdb    ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 2c95e78c-070a-4308-bc21-e56e68be8992 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   2c95e78c-070a-4308-bc21-e56e68be8992
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-40-generic   2c95e78c-070a-4308-bc21-e56e68be8992
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-38-generic   2c95e78c-070a-4308-bc21-e56e68be8992
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-37-generic   2c95e78c-070a-4308-bc21-e56e68be8992
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2c95e78c-070a-4308-bc21-e56e68be8992 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=04F4-4A6B  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.500984192 = 0.537927680    boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  10.121284485 = 10.867646464   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
   4.979160309 = 5.346332672    boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic                 1
  69.916667938 = 75.072450560   boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-38-generic                 1
  10.121284485 = 10.867646464   boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-40-generic                 1
  69.916667938 = 75.072450560   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  10.560054779 = 11.338772480   boot/initrd.img                                2
   6.258510590 = 6.720024576    boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic              5
  70.323657990 = 75.509452800   boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-38-generic              2
  10.560054779 = 11.338772480   boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-40-generic              2
  70.323657990 = 75.509452800   boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18151 Aug 12 09:18 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Jan 13  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Jan 13  2021 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Jan 13  2021 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Jan 13  2021 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jan 13  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jan 13  2021 41_custom

====================== sdb/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================

Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)

========================= sdb/syslinux.cfg (filtered) ==========================

default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title UNetbootin
timeout 100
label unetbootindefault
menu label Default
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
label ubnentry0
menu label ^Help
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 
label ubnentry1
menu label ^64bit session
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper  quiet splash ---
label ubnentry2
menu label ^64bit session (failsafe)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper  noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nomodeset nosmp vga=normal ---
label ubnentry3
menu label Boot-Repair-Disk session
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
label ubnentry4
menu label Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nomodeset nosmp vga=normal --

==================== sdb: Location of files loaded by Grub =====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ===================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.c32                                    1

=============== sdb: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux ================

 ldlinux.c32                        :  not a COM32/COM32R module


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[80265]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 6237: /bin/bash
```

Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how exactly, but i fixed it myself:

Pressed Esc several times until i got to the grub menu. Then selected an older kernel and recovery mode. Then i ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, restarted and it booted again.